# Mixpanel JQL transformations

Tags: mixpanel

I have written a JQL to get the no of events occurred for given start date and end date

```
function main() {
   return Events({
      from_date: params.start_date,
      to_date: params.end_date,
      event_selectors: _.map(params.events, event => ({event: event}))
   }).groupBy(["name","properties.ID"], mixpanel.reducer.count())
  .map(e => { return {"event" : e.key[0], "Id" : e.key[1], "value" : e.value} });
}
```

I am getting the result like this

```
Id    Event   Value
1     Event1    2
2     Event1    3
1     Event2    5
2     Event2    7
```

I want the result to be shown like this

```
Id     Event1   Event2
1         2       5
2         3       7
```

What transformations I need to apply for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try in [console](https://mixpanelplatform.com/apps/getting-started-console/) with this example.

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: '2016-01-01',
    to_date:   '2016-01-07'
  })
  .groupBy(['name', 'properties.$email'], mixpanel.reducer.count())
  //.filter(x => x.key[1] == 'Kathleen.Thompson@gmailx.com') // for testing
  .groupBy(['key.0'], mixpanel.reducer.any())
  .reduce((a, b) => {
    return b.map((obj) => {
      return {
        email: obj.value.key[1],
        name: obj.value.key[0],
        value: obj.value.value
      };
    });
  }).flatten();
}
```

Returning obj with fields - email, name, value.

```
Kathleen.Thompson@gmailx.com    View Blog           1
Kathleen.Thompson@gmailx.com    View Landing Page   4
Kathleen.Thompson@gmailx.com    login               3
Kathleen.Thompson@gmailx.com    pageview            2
```